# sbt subproject aggregation and dependency behavior

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt project with a few subprojects, each of which publishes some artifacts and has a fairly extensive test suite.

When I run the build on my CI server, I want to publish the artifacts to a staging location and run the tests *after* the publishing task. Since others may want the artifacts, I'd like to tell sbt that I want it to build all the artifacts for all subprojects, *then* run all the tests, since by default it seems to run them interleaved in an unspecified order.

I have a `ScopeFilter` giving me access to all my subprojects, so I can make my `ciBuild` task depend on something like the following

```
(test in Test).all(subprojectScopeFilter).dependsOn(myArtifactsTask.all(subprojectScopeFilter))`
```

However, that doesn't seem to have any real effect on the order, and I definitely see some subprojects running tests before others have run their `myArtifactsTask`. I'm guessing that I don't fully understand how `all` works and it might be saying that each independent subproject's `test` task depends on that same subproject's `myArtifactsTask`? If that's the case, how can I specify what I want? Is it documented somewhere that I've missed? The manual describes the basics of `all` but not how it interacts with other constructs.

Comment: Is your `myArtifactsTask` calling `assembly` ? Have you disabled it there via e.g. `test in assembly := {}` ?

Comment: @lpiepiora Can you elaborate on what that would do? I haven't disabled it but I don't quite understand how it would change things.

Comment: Sorry I was too quick to jump into a conclusion. I thought that maybe some of your task already call tests, and SBT evaluates a task key only once. However I think SBT would complain about cyclic dependencies. I will post an answer, which I hope will solve your problem in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

SBT will resolve automatically the order between task and projects and build them in that order.

What you could do is - let's assume you have three projects. Root and two sub-projects. I assume that the key `myArtifactTask` is defined in the root.

#### `project/Build.scala`

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
  val myArtifactTask = TaskKey[Unit]("my-artifact-task", "My Artifact Task")
}
```

The `myArtifactTask` is implemented in both sub-projects.

#### `subproject-a/build.sbt`

```
myArtifactTask := {
  println("myArtifactTask:project-a")
}
```

#### `subproject-a/build.sbt`

```
myArtifactTask := {
  println("myArtifactTask:project-b")
}
```

What you want to do is to define your root's `build.sbt` in a way that it calls myArtifactTask in both projects. Then you could define new task `testedArtifact` which would depend on `myArtifactTask`.

#### build.sbt

```
lazy val testedArtifact = taskKey[Unit]("Runs myArtifactTask followed by tests")

lazy val inAnyProjectButRoot: ScopeFilter = ScopeFilter (
  inAnyProject -- inProjects(ThisProject)
)

myArtifactTask := {
  myArtifactTask.all(inAnyProjectButRoot).value
}

testedArtifact := {
 (test in Test).all(anyProjectButRoot).value
}

testedArtifact <<= testedArtifact.dependsOn(myArtifactTask)
```

Now calling `testedArtifact`in the root project will first call all `myArtifactTask`s in sub-projects followed by tests.

Comment: Hrm, interesting. Would changing the order of the two lines `myArtifactTask.all(...).value` and `(test in Test).all(...).value` change anything? I was under the impression that a set-up like the above would still allow sbt to run tests before all my `myArtifactTask` results, since there is no explicit ordering between them. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're right actually. Maybe the ordering would not be changed, but they could run in parallel. I will update my answer with a better solution.